# apt dist-upgrade failing

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I am trying to run sudo apt dist-upgrade and I am am getting an connection error. It is trying to update the package fwupdate.

Is this because the server is just down, or is there another problem with my system that could be causing this?

```
Err:1 ftp://ftp.cs.mun.ca/pub/mirror/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 fwupdate amd64 0.5-2ubuntu7
  Could not connect to ftp.cs.mun.ca:21 (134.153.48.2), connection timed out
Err:2 ftp://ftp.cs.mun.ca/pub/mirror/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libfwup0 amd64 0.5-2ubuntu7
  Unable to connect to ftp.cs.mun.ca:ftp:
E: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.cs.mun.ca/pub/mirror/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fwupdate/fwupdate_0.5-2ubuntu7_amd64.deb Could not connect to ftp.cs.mun.ca:21 (134.153.48.2), connection timed out

E: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.cs.mun.ca/pub/mirror/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fwupdate/libfwup0_0.5-2ubuntu7_amd64.deb Unable to connect to ftp.cs.mun.ca:ftp:

E: Unable to fetch some archives, try running apt-get update or apt-get --fix-missing
```

.

Comment: Your mirror is Department of Computer Science - Memorial University of Newfoundland. Perhaps it is down? Try a different mirror would be my first guess.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is ocean floor Fibre between Newfoundland and Nova Scotia but assuming there is any mainland Canadian or Eastern US Seaboard mirror should be fine for you to use.